# Array of Pins unexpected results

Tags: arduino

I am using the following code to create an array of pin to use in my Arduino sketch:

```
int LEDS[] = {7, 8, 9, 10};
int wait = 100;
int pinCount = 10;

void setup(){
  for(int PIN=7; PIN < pinCount; PIN++){
    pinMode(PIN, OUTPUT);
  }

  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.print("First LED: ");
  Serial.println(LEDS[0]);

  Serial.print("LED Array Size: ");
  Serial.println(sizeof(LEDS));

  for(int i=0; i < sizeof(LEDS); i++){
    Serial.print("Testing Array Index[");
    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print("] with value: ");
    Serial.print(LEDS[i]);
    Serial.println('***********);
  }
}
```

It seems to me to be quite simple but I get a value twice the actual size of my array and the data in the indexes are not intelligible. Below is sample output:

```
First LED: 7
LED Array Size: 8
Testing Array Index[0] with value: 710794
Testing Array Index[1] with value: 810794
Testing Array Index[2] with value: 910794
Testing Array Index[3] with value: 1010794
Testing Array Index[4] with value: 10010794
Testing Array Index[5] with value: 1010794
Testing Array Index[6] with value: 010794
Testing Array Index[7] with value: 010794
```

Can anyone please assist and help me get the correct number of indexes and the data, please?

Comment: This question just asked here over on stackoverflow.


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18924103/loop-does-not-set-value-correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sizeof` on an array gives you the size of the entire array in bytes. You need to divide this by the size of a single element in order to get the number of elements.

```
sizeof(LEDS) / sizeof(LEDS[0])
```